# pandas convert timestamp to local timezone

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this format of timestamp:
`2023-04-05T10:49:36.292458Z`

but the time zone is incorrect - it is in GMT +1 it should be in GMT +2 (`2023-04-05T11:49:36.292458Z`), so it is an hour behind the correct time.

How do I convert it to the correct timezone, preferably without installing any new packages?

I've tried using `timestamp.tz_locale()` but this adds a +1:00 at the end of the string - is it possible to directly change the string?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the offset you want, you can use:

```
# df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': ['2023-04-05T10:49:36.292458Z']})
df['ts2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts']).dt.tz_convert(None) + pd.DateOffset(hours=1)
print(df)

# Output:
                            ts                        ts2
0  2023-04-05T10:49:36.292458Z 2023-04-05 11:49:36.292458
```

If you just want modify the string, use:

```
# df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': ['2023-04-05T10:49:36.292458Z']})
df['ts2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts']).add(pd.DateOffset(hours=1)).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
print(df)

# Output
                            ts                          ts2
0  2023-04-05T10:49:36.292458Z  2023-04-05T11:49:36.292458Z
```

Comment: Thanks. The values are in string format and some are empty, but when doing something like this `df['dateTimePaid'] = df['dateTimePaid'].apply(lambda a: pd.to_datetime(a).add(pd.DateOffset(hours=1)).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ') if a is not None else None, convert_dtype=False)`, I get `AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'add'`.